# Make grid reverse

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

i have 2 grid rows. how can i make them reverse? direction: rtl revers only text inside grid items. Please, don't offer flex-direction row-reverse. I wanna find how to make same thing with grid. thanks.

Comment: Please post the code you've tried.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3597276+grid+reverse